# actuator logfile on SpringBoot 1.5.* is not working. Http 404

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

Hi I am facing an issue with the Spring Boot (version 1.5.9) `logfile` actuator URL. When I visit `localhost:8080/appctx/logfile`, it throws http 404

Here are the config details.

```
  endpoints.enabled=true
  endpoints.sensitive=false
  management.security.enabled=false
  endpoints.health.sensitive=false
  endpoints.logfile.sensitive=false
  logging.level.org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.logging=DEBUG
```

Answer (score 4):

As stated in [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html) for endpoint `/logfile`:

> Returns the contents of the logfile (if logging.file or logging.path properties have been set). Supports the use of the HTTP Range header to retrieve part of the log file’s content.

You may have not set up `logging.file` or `logging.path` in your `application.properties`.

Try setting:

```
logging.file=myapplication.log
```

More information about logging in Spring Boot you can find [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-logging.html).

Update: Created a working demo [here](https://github.com/lzagkaretos/log-demo) with endpoint `/logfile` up and running.

Comment: yes, I do have it.                  logging.file=./logs/${spring.application.name}.log

Comment: Have you checked if the file is actually written in the disk? Also, you could try something simple `logging.file=mylog.log`.

Comment: Thanks for your responses. I tried that option too. Same app works fine with SB lower versions. (1.3.5)

Comment: I found this in debug logs    EndpointWebMvcManagementContextConfiguration#logfileMvcEndpoint matched:Log File found logging.file /logs/app-name.log (EndpointWebMvcManagementContextConfiguration.LogFileCondition)
 _ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: rg.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.LogFileMvcEndpoint; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)
ConditionalOnEnabledEndpoint All endpoints are enabled by default (OnEnabledEndpointCondition)

Comment: I just created a working demo [here](https://github.com/lzagkaretos/log-demo) if you want to take a look. It's a dummy project with Spring Boot 1.5.9 and a dummy Controller to just log a custom message. Hope you figure it out.

Comment: Thanks. I think I found the issue. The culprit was spring-cloud-starter-config jar.   I changed the version to 
   <version>1.2.0.RELEASE</version> and it is resolved.

Comment: Glad to hear that, I tried to provide some help as I could.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it turned out to be the linux path was incorrect.
Specifically

```
/absolute/path/to/my/app/logs/log-file.log
```

did not work

Once I changed it to a relative path

```
./logs/log-file.log
```

it worked

Hope this helps